# TypeScript difference between these two types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

New to Ts, I'm wondering if there is difference between these two property types.

```
// tooltip says: (parameter) props: React.PropsWithChildren<MyAppProps>
const IndexPage: NextPage<MyAppProps> = (props) => {...}
```

AND

```
// tooltip says: (parameter) props: MyAppProps
const IndexPage: NextPage<MyAppProps> = (props: MyAppProps) => {...}
```

Comment: The only difference is that in the second one, you're explicitly defining the **type** of the `props` argument getting passed to the function. In this case I assume it's a React component, so this means you're explicitly defining the props object for the component to be a `MyAppProps` object

Comment: on second you explicitly set type yourself therefore it's `MyAppProps`;
first type was inferred automatically from `NextPage<MyAppProps>`

Comment: thanks for the answers. so basically, nothing changes?

Comment: There is a difference: props in the first block are typed as `React.PropsWithChildren<MyAppProps>` while in the second block props are typed as `MyAppProps`. This means accessing `props.children` would throw a type error on the second case (assuming `MyAppProps` doesn't actually have `children` defined), while it won't on the first one. Note that there's really no need for you to explicitly type the props if you're typing the page as `NextPage<MyAppProps>`, the props will be typed already.